# How to get words of a string 3 by 3 with overlap?

Tags: c#, regex, string

Let's say I have a sentence like this:

> Regex for taking out words out of a string from a specific position

I need to write a regex that would, combined with a for loop, take out first 3 words from the beginning of the sentence at first (0) loop.

As the loop goes on, the regex would move onto the next part of the sentence, the regex skips the first word and takes the next 3 words in string.

So for example:

```
1st loop I'd get: "Regex for taking";
2nd loop I'd get: "for taking out";
3rd loop I'd get: "taking out words";
```

and so on till the end of the string.

I've figured out how to take a first word out of the string, but that's pretty much it, I'm very new to Regex, and I've done it like this:

```
^([\w\-]+)
```

But this isn't what I need.

Comment: Should it be regex?

Comment: @doctor Not at all, if there is any other solution I'd use it :)

Comment: So, you do not care about punctuation, you only have space separated text chunks?

Comment: Yes that's correct :)

Comment: Regex is certainly the wrong tool to use here; it does not work with overlapping matches (which you are asking for).
You would want something like `((?:[\w\-]+\W){3})` but you would need to run it multiple times over mutilated versions of the string to get all the matches, and then you'd need to put them in order again. It would be a big mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a non regex solution.

```
public static IEnumerable<List<string>> StrangeLoop(string source)
{
    // If word separators are anything other than whitespaces 
    // then change parameters for Split
    var words = source.Split(null); 
    for (int i = 0; i < words.Length - 2; i++)
    {
        yield return new List<string>() { words[i], words[i + 1], words[i + 2] };
    }
}

var sentence = "Regex for taking out words out of a string from a specific position";

foreach (var triad in StrangeLoop(sentence))
{
    //use triad
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest *separating* data *generation* (regular expression or even just a `Split(' ')`) and data *representation* (sliding window):

```
public static IEnumerable<T[]> SlidingWindow<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
                                                int windowSize) {
  if (null == source)
    throw new ArgumentException("source");
  else if (windowSize <= 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("windowSize", 
      "Window size must be positive value");

  List<T> window = new List<T>(windowSize);

  foreach (var item in source) {
    if (window.Count >= windowSize) {
      yield return window.ToArray();

      window.RemoveAt(0);
    }

    window.Add(item);
  }

  // Or (window.Count >= windowSize) if you don't want partial windows 
  if (window.Count > 0)
    yield return window.ToArray();
}
```

Using `SlidingWindow` all you have to do is to generate the matches *as usual*, and then represent them in a different manner (just an additional line).

```
var sentence = "Regex for taking out words out of a string from a specific position";

// Regex solution: get all matches as usual...
var result = Regex
  .Matches(sentence, @"[\w\-]+") // you don't want ^ anchor
  .OfType<Match>()
  .Select(match => match.Value)
  .SlidingWindow(3); // and represent them as sliding windows..

var test = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result
  .Select(line => $"[{string.Join(" ", line)}]")); 

Console.Write(test);
```

The output is

```
[Regex for taking]
[for taking out]
[taking out words]
[out words out]
[words out of]
[out of a]
[of a string]
[a string from]
[string, from, a]
[from a specific]
[a specific position]
```

If you happen to shift from *regular expressions*, to say, a simple `Split` you'll do  it easily:

```
// Split solution: as usual + final representation as sliding window 
var result = sentence
  .Split(' ')        // just split...
  .SlidingWindow(3); // ... and represent as sliding windows
```